# computer giving this error when trying to boot into BIOS/UEFI windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, bios

I was trying to wipe an old computer to sell it, I had Ubuntu 14.04 and Win8.1 dual booted. I put in the windows installation media I had made and it told me it could not use the partition to install windows because it was gpt...

I thought ok I will just reformat it with the windows tool, erased some partitions that I thought were just ubuntu and swap and windows. One of them might have actually been the UEFI partition... :(

Now when I boot I get a quick flashing error and then it boots to the grub loader...

I had to snap a video of the error and then go frame by frame to see it, but here it is.

[image]

so I am almost positive that the partition I deleted was the UEFI, but where can I go from here?

Comment: Boot to a disk with the required EFI driver and format the HDD

Comment: can I get the driver here? I am not seeing it...http://support.fujitsupc.com/CS/Portal/supportsearch.do?srch=DOWNLOADS&Series=A%20Series&Model=AH532&ProductType=Notebook%20PC

Comment: No; you need an .iso with it ( Linux, Windows, etc )

Comment: I have a windows .iso I am using as an installation media but I don't see any direct way to do that... It is still telling me it cannot use the partition because it is of the GPT partition style

Comment: One thing I did not try though was just reformatting the entire drive, all recovery partitions, MSR(reserved) and then doing an install...Should I do this?

Comment: Yes, Windows *should* be able to handle a fully formatted drive absolutely fine.

Comment: you can't install on GPT disk because you booted the installation media in CSM/legacy boot mode. Boot it in UEFI mode and it will work. But I don't get it, didn't you say `I was trying to wipe an old computer to sell it`? Then why install Windows again? Use `clean all` in `diskpart` (with the command prompt in the `Repair your computer`, it will take a pretty long time though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no *UEFI partition*. *UEFI* is a new standard to replace old *BIOS*. You can think of it as a *BIOS* mode and all of its data is stored in your motherboard. There are *EFI partitions* on your hard drives to handle system boot. These partitions are not part of *UEFI* system and will not damage *UEFI* or *BIOS* on your motherboard when deleted. Deletion only makes *Windows* and/or *Ubuntu* unusable, which I read as what you needed.

Your next mistake or misunderstanding was to get rid of *GPT*. *GPT* is not in any way associated with Linux. *Windows* supports *GPT* initialized disks as well unless you're using *Windows XP*. And *GPT* is necessary for *UEFI* booting. You will have to enable a special backward-compatible module called *CSM* in your motherboard settings if you insist on using *UEFI* without *GPT*.

So if you are done with old *Windows* and *Ubuntu*, want to wipe the disk and start from clean-slate:

1. You can create a bootable USB drive or simply burn a DVD from any Windows 8 and above installation ISOs. If you have a genuine Windows disc, use it.
2. Make sure you have enabled *UEFI* and turned **off** any backward-compatible settings. *Windows* and *Ubuntu* work well with *UEFI* and there is no need going back to the 90's.
3. Select your USB/DVD as boot device. When prompted to, select *Custom* installation and **delete** every partition on the disk, until you see only one line `Disk X Unallocated Space` for that disk. (`X` is the disk number.) By far *Windows* will understand you want to do a clean install and convert the disk to meet UEFI standard if necessary.
4. [Optional] If Windows refuses to install, press Shift + F12 to call out command prompt and type: `DiskPart`, `select disk X`, `clean`. (`X` is the disk number showed in step 3.) Be very careful, entering the wrong number may wipe installation media or other disks (if any).
5. Select *unallocated space*, continue installation. *Windows* may inform you that a *EFI* partition will be created to assist system boot.

After installation you will have a clean, new *Windows*. Then install *Ubuntu* if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to just type `exit` at the bash prompt and then it booted the next device which was my usb.